# How to delay an event until another event is finished in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event defined on an element and I also have a `click` event defined on the same element. Now when I `click` on the element and move the cursor away from the element the `click` event gets triggered first and then the `mouseleave` event but I want to delay the `click` event until `mouseleave` event is finished. How can I do so ?

**My code:**

```js
$("#ele").mouseenter( function(){
  $('#ele').text('onMouseEnter');
});

$("#ele").click( function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  $('#ele').text('onClick');
});

$("#ele").mouseleave( function(){
  $('#ele').text('onMouseLeave');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='ele'> 
  Testing...
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Please don't suggest a solution that would contain part of `click` event code in the `mouseleave` event because I am also triggering the `click` event manually on window resize. Which would not execute that part of `click` event code which would be in the `mouseleave` event.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a flag checking if the element is clicked, if it is clicked then set that flag to true. And now in mouseleave check if the flag is true and if it is true then execute the click function.

See this below.

```js
var isClicked = false;

function onClickDelayed() {
  $('#ele').text('onClick');
}

$("#ele").mouseenter(function() {
  $('#ele').text('onMouseEnter');
});

$("#ele").click(function(e) {
  isClicked = true;
});

$("#ele").mouseleave(function() {
  $('#ele').text('onMouseLeave');

  if (isClicked)
    onClickDelayed();
  isClicked = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='ele'>
  Testing...
</div>
```

Comment: good one. I was saying the same thing, but you put it a bit earlier.

Comment: I have already tried that. I want to separate the code of click event from the mouseleave event. I don't want any code of click event in mouseleave event.

Comment: Isn't there a jQuery function or anything like that. Which allows you to execute event only after the completion of some other event ?

Answer (score 0):

What comes to my mind is that you can make some variable, like:

```
mouseHit = false;
$("#ele").click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  mouseHit = true;
});

$("#ele").mouseleave( function(){
  $('#ele').text('onMouseLeave');
  if (mouseHit) {
     $('#ele').text('onClick');
     mouseHit = !mouseHit;
  }
});
```

in this case your variable is responsible for making sure that previous click event was triggered, but you do actual action in mouseleave event.